# Release sequence code snippet giving random behaviour

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic, stdatomic

I was working on one of the examples from the book Concurrency With Modern C++ by Rainer Grimm and I found this code snippet (edited somewhat to get better undestanding of the concept). The code snippet is related to top `Release Sequence`

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
int work{0};
std::atomic<int> ready{0};

void consumer() {
    while(!(ready.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acquire) > 0)) {
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms); 
        }
        work--;
    std::cout<<"soemthing is here" << work <<std::endl;
}

void producer() {
    work = 2019;
    ready.store(2, std::memory_order_release);

}

int main () {
    std::thread prod(producer);
    std::thread con(consumer);
    std::thread con2(consumer);

    prod.join();
    con.join();
    con2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program comes out to be
`soemthing is here2018\nsoemthing is here2017\n`
`soemthing is heresoemthing is here20172017\n\n`
`soemthing is here2018soemthing is here2017\n\n`
`soemthing is heresoemthing is here20172017\n\n`

Can anyone explain why there is so much difference in the output and how this output can be justified using acquire-release semantics and release sequence.
Note: `\n` is used to represent output of `std::endl;`

Comment: What, exactly you are asking about? Both the usage of `std::cout`, and `work--;` are unsynchronized modification. Due to this, your code exhibits undefined behavior, and any reasoning about the specific behavior of undefined behavior is pointless.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius How the synchronisation can be done between `std::cout` and `work--` without using lock here. And also how the line `std::cout<<"soemthing is here" << work <<std::endl;` can be made to print output as `soemthing is here2018\nsoemthing is here2017\n` instead `soemthing is heresoemthing is here20172017\n\n`?

Comment: 1) "_How the synchronisation can be done between `std::cout` and `work--` without using lock here._" You need to have a lock, so that the object is accessed only from a single thread at a time. 2) "_And also how the line `std::cout<<"soemthing is here" << work <<std::endl;` can be made to print output as `soemthing is here2018\nsoemthing is here2017\n` instead `soemthing is heresoemthing is here20172017\n\n`?_" I already told you: by synchronizing the access to `std::cout`. It is not, inherently, thread safe.

Comment: @PiyushVijay Why would use iostream w/o locking?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has UB because `work` isn't `atomic<int>`.  But your producer and both consumers write it without synchronization.  The symptom in this case is that the compiler optimized `consumer` to keep its own local copy of `work` in a register so you get numbers repeated, once from each thread.

And of course you need to use `int tmp = work--;` to do one `fetch_sub`, instead of an atomic decrement and then later reading a value that might have changed.

---

**The other showstopper is that three separate `cout` calls for the three separate `<<` operators are not a single atomic print.**

`cout` itself is thread-safe, though.

You could **print into a full line (including `\n`) into a private string or char buffer and then safely `cout` that**.  `std::endl` isn't magic; it's literally identical to `<< '\n'` and flushing the stream (in case it was full-buffered so `\n` didn't already do that).

e.g. `sprintf` or `stringstream` or whatever.

That would make sure that whole lines like `soemthing is here2018\n` are always contiguous.  (You probably want to spellcheck and leave a trailing space).

That doesn't guarantee they'll print in numeric order, though.  One consumer might decrement first, but the other thread decrements second but then gets the lock (inside `std::cout`) first to print a lower-numbered line first.